# C fill char array with n values leads to problem

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, char

I want to give the program an integer value from 1 to 26 (doesn't need to be hardcoded) that creates a char Array that is filled with the letters from A to letter n.
This is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    char comb[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        comb[i] = 65 + i;
    
    printf("%s", comb);
}
```

The problem is, that if i hand over values from 8 - 15 and 24 - 26, the output shows something like this:
ABCDEFGH�������

However, if i hardcode n to be one of the problematic values from above, the output is just right.

Can somebody explain to me, why the program puts out the extra �.
Thanks

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. For a string to be properly handles as a string, you need to add the null-terminator `'\0'` at the end, and of course allocate space for it.

Comment: My guess would be that the string is nut null terminated and therefore those extra chars are just garbage reciding in memory. Reboot and you might see different results. A solution is to make your `comb` array n+1 in size and add a (char) 0 to the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks, so if i understand that right, the code must be looking something like this?
char comb[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        comb[i] = 65 + i;
    comb[n] = '\0'

Comment: @Slashstep correct, that should fix the problem :) - [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/9Yxs8Esqr)

Comment: Great, that fixed it. Thanks for the fast help.

Comment: On another few notes, please try to avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you the value `65` you mean the ASCII value for `'A'` then please use `'A'`. But also note that what you're doing is not portable. There are allowed character encodings where the letters are not in a contiguous sequence like ASCII. And lastly, by accepting user input like that without any validation, the user might give some invalid input, which could lead to all kinds of trouble, the least being that it might be out of range of the upper-case letters in ASCII.

Comment: Lastly, a possible better solution (but not portable as it still relies on ASCII or similar encodings) is to print the characters one by one in the loop instead of gathering them in an array. For example like `for (int ch = 'A'; ch < 'A' + n && ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) { putchar(ch); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The standard way to convert a string to a numeric type in C is to use the `strto*` family of functions. In your case, you would want something like:

   ```
   int count = strtol(argv[1], // String
                      NULL, // Optional output pointer to where the scan stopped 
                      10) // Radix
   ```

   I'd also check that `argc > 2`, i.e. that `argv[1]` was actually passed by the user.
2. `%s` expects a pointer to a *null terminated string*. In other words, `printf` has no way of knowing where the string argument stops until it sees the `'\0'`, so what you're seeing is some other part of your process memory being printed out as text.  To fix: allocate `n + 1` for `comb`, and `memset(comb, n + 1, 0);` before the loop, or set `comb[n] = '\0'` right after the loop.